# Is a planet sized cell possible?

Tags: xenobiology

So, out in the more backwater parts of the galaxy, all sorts of weird entities and indescribable sights are common. Out in the Kepler Nebula, 13 lightyears north south of Talus V, there is a Eukaryotic single-cell, the size of a planet, that, contrary to what you would expect, is conscious and has amazing, god like powers, like telekinesis, telepathy, teleportation mind reading, and the ability to create materials out of pure energy. It is actually much more evolved and superior to life forms like us. Let’s call it Eukary.

It is about the size of Pluto, and can be mistaken for a planet by far away travelers. It can destroy spaceships 1,000 lightyears away, just with the sheer power of its telekinesis, create planets with its “Mind”, and use mind control to subjugate entire species. The reason my main characters go there is to try and ally with it so they can win the Von Neumann-Biological war.

My question is, ignoring all its amazing powers, could a Eukaryotic cell survive out in space, what would be the main problems in doing this, and what could be done to solve them?

***Additional Information***

It’s an animal cell structure, and it isn’t the only “Super-Celled” organism out there. Their are less powerful prokaryotic cells, about the size of large asteroids, but our friend Eukary is the only one of its kind, a Eukaryote. These creatures, the prokaryotes, live for about 4 billion years, and Eukary can live for eons.

Comment: What kind of cell is this? What does it need? a human blood cell, for instance will have different from that of a dog's muscle cell. Most cell require several materials (for "building" or "repairing" part in for example). What does your cell need to do? does it reproduce? does it just 'live'?

Comment: @Rick M. Neither. Think about it as the earliest form of eukaryote that evolved, the most general, basic type. It can reproduce, but it prefers not to, wanting himself to be the last of his kind. It does need a supply of energy to survive. A building materials should be brought up in the answers.

Comment: If it's creating materials out of pure energy (we'll call it "magic"), where is it getting that energy from?  Destruction at a distance (via "telekinesis") doesn't require much more energy conceptually than a laser would.  Creating matter is an entirely different ball game.

Comment: @jdunlop: You’re right, it’s magic. Magic is weird, so try not to think about that power to hard

Comment: What would you name a cell? How would you draw a border? In our biology this concept is well defined, but xenobiology requires more abstract definition for a word "cell" to make any sense. So what is your definition of a cell?

Comment: @Molot: This entity is both a cell and not a cell. Both a ln organism and not an organism. “Cell” is the easiest word I could use to describe it, as it is a being of pure unity and oneness. I define a cell as a being of oneness

Comment: @DTCooper - if you define a cell as a being of oneness, and this planet-creature is a being of oneness, the question would seem tautological.

Comment: This Q has been nominated to be reopened, but as it sits, it is unanswerable (if only for being too story-based).  Can a single-cell organism survive in space?  No, no more than a multi-cell organism can.  Can it be the size of Pluto?  No, but that's the purpose of suspension of disbelief. Can it be intelligent?  No (and it's a whomping suspension of disbelief to choke that one down). Therefore, any possible answer to the question that permits the OP to continue is either story-based or POB. The Q should stay closed until the OP definitively explains what his Eukaryote really is.  (*continue*)

Comment: And for the record, DT, "it is a cell and not a cell" is a wholly unacceptable description that will gurantee the Q stays closed.  Please leave the philosophy at the door.  If you can't describe it, then we can't answer a question about it, because no one (including yourself) knows what "it" is.

Comment: Ah, another excellent worldbuilding question! A huge single celled being inhabiting the farther reaches of Space! Forget about the gripes of this being "too opinion based!" Let's just try and answer an intriguing question! Yes, it should be reopened, as it's this kind of creativity that makes worldbuilding an art of wonder and delight!

Comment: @elemtilas It seems to me that you're attempting to use sarcasm to bring across the point that we both agree on (which is that the current ruleset needs to be changed to disallow questions like these, or other number crunching questions) but this is a very poor method as tone of voice very rarely comes across properly in text form.

Comment: @JBH: No, it is a cell, on that one comment I was just joking around

Comment: @JBH: it’s a normal cell

Comment: @Aify Actually, NO sarcasm at all! I think this is actually an interesting question, and a creative setting to boot. As regards the rules, the community has spoken, the Mods have spoken, and, frankly, I don't think that's the battle I wish to keep fighting. If they want to allow every question that comes through, honestly, then they'll get the forum they have asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stretch the definition of *cell*, I don't see why it couldn't be big in a low- or zero-g environment. It's going to be wildly more complex than a microscopic cell due to the size alone. I have a hard time imagining it being more like a cell than a highly complex multicellular organism, though. Even if it looks like a single-celled Eukaryote it's going to be vastly more complicated than any life form ever encountered by humanity. Major questions will involve *why* it would get so big, but we're deep into fantastic territory anyways with this.

As for surviving in space... that's harder. Problems include:

- Heat: If any internal processes depend on the organism not being frozen, it'll need to generate a tremendous amount of internal heat. And it will need to be able to retain and regulate that heat in the extremely cold environment of space. Nuclear reactions might do it, but those pose serious problems for genetic material.
- Protection from radiation and cosmic rays: These are similar dangers to radiation from internal processes and can seriously degrade physical material, but the organism will be exposed to these pretty much constantly no matter what.
- Getting food and other raw material: Space is mostly empty, but life forms need to obtain physical matter to incorporate into their own physical structures. That's massively more an issue for an organism that is the size of a dwarf planet.
- Obtaining energy: Physical processes that allow for life require energy. Given the emptiness of space and the spacing between stars, it's going to be hard for such an organism to get much reliably. As above, internal nuclear reactions might provide this, but cause problems of their own.
- Gravity: Depending on the density of the organism, it's likely to have its own, non-negligible gravity. It will be hard to keep it from collapsing on itself, depending on what it's composed of. It will also attract matter, like asteroids, which could cause serious damage.
- Locomotion: Movement in space requires some sort of propulsion, and something this big would have a lot of mass to get moving. It would need some mechanism for propulsion, which may in turn produce more specific dietary needs.
- Thought/Mechanical Complexity: Something like this would be *incredibly* intricate, with perhaps millions upon millions of processes needing to be coordinated together to keep the cell whole and functioning. Whether or not the thing can "think", as we generally use that word, it will need a lot of processing power to be able to persist. That also requires a lot of energy.
- Superior Design: Whether intentionally crafted or shaped by practical development (a la evolutionary pressures) this thing will have a lot of complex needs and relatively little room for error. Building something mechanical like this is currently well beyond human engineering capability, for example.
- Plausible Genesis: Where would this thing come from? It would be a narrow evolutionary path (probably to the point of impossibility) that would produce something like this in response to normal evolutionary pressures. As for design, you would really be hand-waving away some force or organization with design and engineering skills beyond imagining, especially if it can cope with all of the above.

Absent it's supernatural qualities, I'd be pretty skeptical that something like this is literally possible. But as as science fiction element, there are plenty of examples of creatures that live in space.

I wouldn't worry about plausibility, as you're likely past that right from the start. Ancient and unimaginably excellent design will do the trick, but will defy your efforts to explain the organism in much detail. And with its supernatural qualities you can just assert pretty much whatever properties you want, in which case plausibility is a non-issue.

Comment: Better laid-out than the answer I was putting together.  I would argue that such a "cell" would be related to eukaryotes here on earth in the same way that a campfire is like a red giant star.  They both emit light in similar spectra, and there the similarities end.